# How to extend more IO from a Raspberry Pi board?

Tags: gpio

I am designing a locker system with Raspberry pi 4B and inching switches to detect if the things inside the locker are removed or not.
[image]
It has 34 lockers, and I have already found a proper locker-extension board and electrical locks. The board receive RS485 signal from Raspberry and control locks by turning on and off lock current. However, I still need 34 IOs connecting to 34 inching switches, but a Raspberry has only 27 IOs. There is still 7 IOs short. Is there any way to increase IO numbers of a Raspberry board? Maybe like an RS-485 IO extension board receiving RS-485 signal from Raspberry and controls the extended IOs and return status?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to increase number of GPIO for Raspberry Pi or any microcontroller such as:

- Using multiplexers. There are many types. You can read up about it here. https://www.electronicshub.org/multiplexerandmultiplexing/
- Using some I2C or SPI GPIO expansion such as https://learn.adafruit.com/mcp230xx-gpio-expander-on-the-raspberry-pi

  - There are available HAT for this: https://thepihut.com/products/modmypi-mcp23017-hat-32-channel-io-expansion-hat
- Using USB to connect to devices with additional GPIO. Perhaps connect to Arduino. There are also many GPIO expander shields for Arduino. With USB hubs, you can probably connect to as many Arduinos as you like.

Comment: Thank you very much! The I2C GPIO expansion is exactly what I need. Earlier I use GPIO extender as google keyword, and find only something extend the original GPIO to another board, instead of increasing IO number. Now I know the exact keyword should be GPIO expansion. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, it is usually called GPIO expansion or expander.